# argparse: Handle certain arguments out of order

Tags: python, argparse

I have a python application that has a few repeatable arguments for which the interleaved order matters. e.g.  `app -f 1 -b 2 -f 3` is not the same command as `app -f 1 -f 3 -b 2`.

The issue is that I also have verbosity control arguments, and I want that to impact the logging behavior of the code being executed within the actions.

Is there a way to have `argparse` handle certain arguments out-of-order so that the verbosity control can be applied before other arguments are handled, regardless of where it is present in `argv`?

```py
# test.py
import argparse
import logging

def foo(x):
  logging.info(f'hi foo {x}')

def bar(x):
  logging.debug(f'hi bar {x}')

def SetVerbosity(log_level):
    class Action(argparse.Action):
        def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
            logging.getLogger(values).setLevel(level=log_level)

    return Action

class PerformFoo(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        foo(values)

class PerformBar(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        bar(values)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', nargs='?', action=SetVerbosity(logging.INFO))
parser.add_argument('-vv',             nargs='?', action=SetVerbosity(logging.DEBUG))

parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo', metavar='VAL', action=PerformFoo, help='Do a foo')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--bar', metavar='VAL', action=PerformBar, help='Do a bar')

logging.basicConfig()
parser.parse_args()
```

```sh
# No problem
python test.py -v -f 1 -b 2 -f 3
INFO:root:hi foo 1
INFO:root:hi foo 3

# kind of unfortunate
app -f 1 -b 2 -f 3 -v
*crickets*
```

As a fallback, I know I could just accumulate the `-f` and `-b` in a heterogenous "stuff-to-do" list and handle them after the fact. But I'd rather not jump through that additional hoop if there's a reasonably straightforward way to address this without an added layer of indirection.

Answer (score 1):

And as per the time-honored tradition, I managed to figure an answer shortly after posting the question.

In case someone else lands here, I managed to do it by creating a second parser and invoke it using `parse_known_args()` so that the non-verbosity arguments are ignored.

```
verbosityParser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

verbosityParser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', nargs='?', action=SetVerbosity(logging.INFO))
verbosityParser.add_argument('-vv',             nargs='?', action=SetVerbosity(logging.DEBUG))

# Still add verbosity to the "main" parser so that it shows up in help
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('-vv',             nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo', metavar='VAL', action=PerformFoo, help='Do a foo')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--bar', metavar='VAL', action=PerformBar, help='Do a bar')

logging.basicConfig()
verbosityParser.parse_known_args()
parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `foo` and `var` when the options are seen. Instead, collect a list of actions to perform once you have parsed all the options.

Something like

```
import argparse
import logging

def foo(x):
  pass

def bar(x):
  pass

def SetVerbosity(value):
    class Action(argparse.Action):
        def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
            logging.getLogger(values).setLevel(level=value)

    return Action

class PerformFoo(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        namespace.to_do += [(foo, values)]

class PerformBar(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        namespace.to_do += [(bar, values)]

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', nargs='?', action=SetVerbosity(logging.INFO))
parser.add_argument('-vv',             nargs='?', action=SetVerbosity(logging.DEBUG))

parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo', metavar='VAL', action=PerformFoo, help='Do a foo')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--bar', metavar='VAL', action=PerformBar, help='Do a bar')

args = parser.parse_args()

for f, v in args.to_do:
    f(v)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I do state in the question that I'm explicitly wondering if there is an alternative to this, which is my current fallback.

Comment: No, there isn't. Arguments are simply processed in the order they appear.

Comment: `argparse` is not well suited for handling arguments where order matters.  The underlying parsing method tries to handle arguments as given without retaining information on order.  Special actions can change that.  `append` for example allows for repeated optionals.  Your special actions also do it, but in a sense they violate the core `argparse` idea - parse and then act.

Comment: @hpaulj Arguably, `version` and `help` violate that idea as well (though they both exit the script, making them somewhat of a different special case).